# multiple projects in a solution each with a wwwroot asp.net 5 mvc 6

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, multi-project, wwwroot

My colleague and I will build a mvc 6 multi project solution. So far everything is ok. Now we are on the stage that we have 3 different MVC projects in the solution. Everyone has it's own wwwroot. And in the end every project could stand for it self (with little changes).

What is in this case the best approach to copy/export the content to the wwwroot of the main project. The goal is that every project has it's own dependencies on .js files etc. pp.

Are there other solution for this task?

Thanks for your help and inputs.

Kind regards
Bella